# Send an Alert to user based on changes in the database row

Tags: postgresql, redis, architecture, queue

There are 10, 000 users. Each can define up to 500 conditions for an enterprise supply chain inventory.

An example of a condition could be

```
Group1
Item in InventoryX > 5000 AND colourItem == Red
AND Group2
Item in InventoryY > 4000 and colourItem == Green
```

Whenever the state of the database (single row in InventoryX, InventoryY, and colourItem columns) meets to the condition mentioned above, the user who has created the alert should be notified.

The first solution that comes to mind is to continuously keep polling the database, at a given time interval (say 1 minute) but the problem with it would be every minute there will be 10000 X 500 polls.

This is difficult to scale.

We also need to keep in mind that the user's are given a simple front-end to create conditions, and they can update these conditions as per their whim. No hard coding can work.

What would be a better architecture/project to be used to achieve the same?

Database = PostgreSQL.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html
Appears difficult to implement since there is no ease of usage for so many conditions.

Comment: perhaps best to monitor the event that causes this data to change and check on the changed item ?

Answer (score 0):

You only have three options:

1. Poll the database for changes (which as you say, gets expensive).
2. Check all the rules as the changes are made.
3. Make a note of changed data as changes are made and check that changed subset in batches.

Whether you prefer #2 or #3 depends on how many rules there are, how long it takes to check them for each changed row and whether you can usefully summarise changes or merge alerts.

Both #2 and #3 would use one or more triggers. Option #2 would run the rules and add entries to an "alerts" queueing table (or `NOTIFY` a listening process to send an alert, or set a flag in memcached/redis etc).

Option #3 would just note either the IDs of changed rows, or perhaps the details of the change and you would have another process read the changes and generate alerts. This gives you the opportunity to notice that the same change was made twice and only send 1 alert or similar if that is useful to you.

Comment: for option #3 when you mention "have another process to read the changes" what would this be a RabbitMQ pub-sub? or a python async script again polling this subset?

Comment: I'd start with something trivial like a python script run from a cron job and build out from there.